# jquery to generate dynamic list

Tags: jquery

I want to dynamically add comments to an html list .But the comments should go in the specific list  according to the form from which it is sent.
Say if it is from form id=1 then it should go in form id=1 and if it is from form id=2 then it should go in the list form id=2
Here is my code. I had already wasted many hours upon researching through it on web. Please help..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10/jquery.min.js">  </script>         
        <script>
            var user_name = 'Danil';
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.comment_entry form').submit(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var currentId=$('form',this).attr('id');
                    var comment = $("input[type='text',id=currentId]").val();
                    $(".comments#"+currentId).append('<li><a class="commenter_name" href="/">' +     user_name + '</a>' + comment + '</li>');
                    $("input[type='text',id=currentId]").val("");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="1" class="comments">
        </ul>
        <div  class="comment_entry">
            <form id="1" method="post" >
                <input id="1"  type="text" placeholder="Leave comment" />
                <input type="submit" value="submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <ul id="2" class="comments">
        </ul>
        <div  class="comment_entry">
            <form id="2" method="post" >
                <input id="2" type="text" placeholder="Leave comment" />
                <input  type="submit" value="submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems here

The `id` of an element should be unique, you have 3 elements with id 1, I've changed the ids to `c1`, `f1` and `i1` for the `comments` div, form and input field

Try

```
<ul id="c1" class="comments">
</ul>
<div  class="comment_entry">
    <form id="f1" method="post" >
        <input id="i1"  type="text" placeholder="Leave comment" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
</div>
<ul id="c2" class="comments">
</ul>
<div  class="comment_entry">
    <form id="f2" method="post" >
        <input id="i2" type="text" placeholder="Leave comment" />
        <input  type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

then

```
var user_name = 'Danil';

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.comment_entry form').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var currentId=$(this).attr('id').substring(1);
        var comment = $('#i'+currentId).val();

        $("#c"+currentId).append('<li><a class="commenter_name" href="/">' +     user_name + '</a>' + comment + '</li>');
        $('#i'+currentId).val("");
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/f6MrN/)

Answer (score 0):

It's invalid to have multiple elements with the same `id` attribute. Your code has some other bugs, but start by prefixing the id attributes with the element name - so `<ul id="ul-1">` instead of `<ul id="1">`. You'll also want to use jquery's native id-selector syntax: `$("#ul-1")`. Lastly, variables are not interpolated into JS strings, so things like this won't work:

```
var currentId=$('form',this).attr('id');
var comment = $("input[type='text',id=currentId]").val();
```

You have to build the string yourself, something like `$("#input-" + currentId + ").val()`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, and don't forget that ID should be unique!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <head>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>    
 <script>  
var user_name = 'Danil';
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.commentBut``ton').click(function() {
        var currentId = $(this).parents('form').attr('id');
        var comment = $('input[id="input-' + currentId + '"]').val();
        $('ul[id="list-' + currentId + '"]').append('<li><a class="commenter_name" href="#">' + user_name + '</a> ' + comment + '</li>');
        $('input[id="input-'+currentId+'"]').val('');
   });
});
   </script>
   </head>

    <body>
    List 1
    <ul id="list-1" class="comments">
    </ul>
      <div  class="comment_entry">
         <form id="1" method="post">
           <input id="input-1" type="text" placeholder="Leave comment" />
          <input type="button" value="submit" class="commentButton"/>
         </form>
     </div>

     List 2
     <ul id="list-2" class="comments">
     </ul>
    <div  class="comment_entry">
    <form id="2" method="post" >
        <input id="input-2" type="text" placeholder="Leave comment" />
        <input  type="button" value="submit" class="commentButton"/>
    </form>
     </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```